# MySQL error #1064 in CREATE TABLE

Tags: mysql, syntax, foreign-keys

Here's my sql for two tables I'm creating:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tbl_a(
    id INT(6) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
)ENGINE = INNODB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tbl_b(
    id INT(6) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id),
    FOREIGN KEY id REFERENCES tbl_a(id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
)ENGINE = INNODB;
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'REFERENCES a(id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE )ENGINE = INNODB' at line 4
```

Could anyone suggest me a solution, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `()` around the key name

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tbl_b(
    id INT(6) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES tbl_a(id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
)ENGINE = INNODB;
```

Comment: It gave me an error: #1072 - Key column 'f_id' doesn't exist in table...Okay, just edited it according to your update and it works. Why do we have to put () around the key name?

Comment: Well that is how the syntax must be. See [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html).